# Query to Find Duplicates and Add Alias Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access database named `testdb`, with table name `table1`.

The table has 2 fields `BinNo` and `Prodcode`.

`BinNo` has many duplicate rows and I want to group `BinNo` wherever it has a duplicate row to create new alias column.

Given the following data:

```
+---------+----------+
|  BinNo  | Prodcode |
+---------+----------+
| Bin no1 | Pro 1    |
| Bin no1 | Pro 2    |
| Bin no1 | Pro 3    |
| Bin no2 | Pro 4    |
| Bin no2 | Pro 5    |
+---------+----------+
```

Here is the desired result:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  BinNo  | Prodcode1 | Prodcode2 | Prodcode3 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Bin no1 | Pro 1     | Pro 2     | Pro 3     |
| Bin no2 | Pro 4     | Pro 5     |           |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to do, but to do what you asked start by adding two columns to your table.
[image]

you usually need a primary key at some point so adding the ID column is good practice even if I don't use it here. Then add a column with your eventual row titles.  I called this column CodeOrder.  To convert the CodeOrder column to a row make a crosstab query.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8
Open the query designer and make it look like:
[image]

Note the Crosstab and total rows on the variables.  These rows will be added when you find and select crosstab on the ribbon.  Note it is important to choose the right summary function for the value variable which is first for these data.  I hope this helps :)