# Access sql query multipul record to single record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access database named testdb, with table name table1.

The table has 2 fields BinNo and Prodcode.

BinNo has many duplicate rows and I want to group BinNo wherever it has a duplicate row to create new alias column (like single record).

Given the following data:

```
 +---------+----------+
 |  BinNo  | Prodcode |
 +---------+----------+
 | Bin no1 | Pro 1    |
 | Bin no1 | Pro 2    |
 | Bin no1 | Pro 3    |
 | Bin no2 | Pro 4    |
 | Bin no2 | Pro 5    |
 +---------+----------+
```

Here is the desired result:

```
 +---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 |  BinNo  | Prodcode1 | Prodcode2 | Prodcode3 |
 +---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 | Bin no1 | Pro 1     | Pro 2     | Pro 3     |
 | Bin no2 | Pro 4     | Pro 5     |           |
 +---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to Find Duplicates and Add Alias Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148741/query-to-find-duplicates-and-add-alias-column)

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

This is really painful in MS Access.  You can do this using conditional aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
select t1.binno,
       max(iif(seqnum = 1, prodcode, null)) as prodcode_1,
       max(iif(seqnum = 2, prodcode, null)) as prodcode_2,
       max(iif(seqnum = 3, prodcode, null)) as prodcode_3
from (select t1.*,
             (select count(*)
              from table1 as tt1
              where tt1.binno = t1.binno and tt1.prodcode <= t1.prodcode
             ) as seqnum
      from table1 as t1
     ) as t1
group by t1.binno;
```

The subquery is essentially implementing `row_number()`, which is not available in MS Access.

Comment: Dear Gordon Linoff, Can you please read my new question...about the same problem

Comment: @SatigerB . . . New questions should be asked as *questions*, not as edits to already answered questions.